# Stay in visual mode when in command mode and pressing escape

Tags: command-line, visual-mode

Suppose we do the following steps:

1. Visually select something
2. Type `:some stuff`
3. press escape

when we do the last step, the command mode is exited but also we are left in normal mode - not visual mode. How do I make Vim go back to visual mode with the current selection when pressing escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go back to the previous selection with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>. So after you type <kbd>esc</kbd> you can type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> and the old selection is active again. (see [`gv`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#gv))

To do this automatically is a little difficult. I did not find a full working solution right away. My basic idea was to map <kbd>esc</kbd> in command mode (see [`:cnoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:cnoremap)).

A plain

```
cnoremap <esc> <esc>gv
```

does not really work well as it is *always* used the pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> in the command line. But I think it should only activate the last selection when you entered the command line from visual mode.

Now I thought about an expression mapping (see [`:map-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-expression)).  But if I use [`mode()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#mode()) like this it obviously doesn't work as we are always in command mode:

```
cnoremap <expr> <esc> mode()=='v' ? "\<esc>gv" : "\<esc>"
```

But if we can save the information that we have been in visual mode when pressing <kbd>:</kbd> in the first place we can use it to do the right thing when pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> later.  For this we need two functions and two mappings:

```
let s:was_visual = 0
function! EnterCommandLineFromVisualMode()
  let s:was_visual = 1
  return ':'
endfunction
function! HandleEscapeInCommandLine()
  if s:was_visual
    let s:was_visual = 0
    return "\<esc>gv"
  endif
  return "\<esc>"
endfunction
vnoremap <expr> : EnterCommandLineFromVisualMode()
cnoremap <expr> <esc> HandleEscapeInCommandLine()
```

Put this code into your vimrc or a new file in the plugin directory and it should work.  The result might be inconsistent when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in the command line though as the `s:was_visual` variable will not get updated. You will need an extra `cmap` for this. Maybe there are other corner cases like this that I did not think of right now.

Comment: Man, that was a rather unexpectedly complex solution! Thank you for all your time and effort you put into this!

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again, but I have noticed a bug with the code you wrote above. Suppose I type `:something` and then decide I don't want to run it, so press escape. But the command still runs, and logs an error saying `Not an editor command: something`. I have tried debugging this, and have determined that simply having the mapping calling the functions causes the bug to occur. What do you think about this?